# Build failed with an exception flutter project

Tags: flutter

i get flutter project source code from my teacher to run into my computer...
and I'm an absolute beginner...
I found errors and I don't know why cause the code is running normally on my teacher's computer
the debug console error is

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)

 is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\manou\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f\jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: C:\Users\manou\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f\jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

 Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

can you please help me with that

Comment: what your Android Studio Version? please Update Android Studio hope it will solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Just go to `android/app/build.gradle` and change `compileSdkVersion` to `31`